Efficient way to solve class assignment problem
I am trying to solve a class assignment problem using a factor graph. For each pixel I have a state
$\boldsymbol{s} =
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
p_1\\
\vdots\\
p_n\\
\end{array}
\right)$,
where each $p_i$ is the probability of this pixel belonging to class $i$. This means that $0 \leq p_i \leq 1$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{\boldsymbol{s}} p_i = 1$.
In my graph each pixel is connected to $m = 5$ factors, four of which are connecting it with its adjacent pixels and one for the actual measurement. For each of these connections to a pixel's graph neighbor $j$ I am computing two energy vectors
$\boldsymbol{a}_j =
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
a_{j,1}\\
\vdots\\
a_{j,n}\\
\end{array}
\right)$
and
$\boldsymbol{b}_j =
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
b_{j,1}\\
\vdots\\
b_{j,n}\\
\end{array}
\right)$,
where $a_{j,i}$ is the energy of assigning class $i$ given the state of $j$, and $b_i$ the energy for NOT assigning class $i$ (with $a_{j,i}, b_{j,i} \geq 0$). As such, the compatibility function $\psi$ of $p_i$ with $j$ becomes:
$\psi(p_i, j) =  p_i  a_{j,i} + (1 - p_i) b_{j,i} = p_i (a_{j,i} - b_{j,i}) + b_{j,i}$,
leading into the optimization problem
$\min{s} \sum_{i=1}^n \psi(p_i, j)^2$,
for a single factor, or
$\min{s} \sum_{j=1}^m \sum_{i=1}^n \psi(p_i, j)^2$.
respectively.
Since $\psi(p_i, j)$ is linear, getting the gradients is trivial. However, doing so ignores the aforementioned constrains about $\boldsymbol{s}$ holding normalized probabilities.
For prototyping I reduced the length of $\boldsymbol{s}$ by one element, encoded the probability of $p_1$ in the length of the remaining vector and tossed everything into a non-linear solver. By updating the probabilities of all pixels iteratively the entire system then finally converges to a minimal energy state. While the whole thing works fine, this approach creates a runtime issue.
From what I read about factor graphs, the common strategy for turning the energy term into an updated probability $q_i$ is to use
$q_{i} = A \cdot \text{exp}(-\psi(p_i, j)^2)$,
where $A$ is a constant normalization factor. Doing so would would help me to enforce $0 \leq p_i \leq 1$. According to this article one can even get rid of the entire minimization process when using a linear compatibility function. However, I'm still lacking a way to make sure the sum of $\boldsymbol{s}$ stays $1$.
Is there any elegant way of solving this?
